# unexpected array size: new_size=1, got array with arr_size=0

Tags: python, scipy

I have `python 3.7.4` script as below, so when I compile I get this error:

> unexpected array size: new_size=1, got array with arr_size=0

My original codes:

```
...
# (r, theta, phi)
class spherical_utilities(object):
    def __init__(self, ng, n, lab):
        self.n = n
        self.ng = ng
        self.set_ngauss()
        self.set_funcs_ang()
        self.set_all_layers(lab)

    def set_ngauss(self):
        k, w = ps_roots(self.ng)
        self.knots, self.weights = k * pi, w * pi
        self.thetas = self.knots
        self.sint = sin(self.thetas)
        self.cost = cos(self.thetas)
        self.tgt = tan(self.thetas)
        self.ctgt = 1 / self.tgt

    def set_funcs_ang(self):
        P = array([special.lpmn(self.n, self.n, ct) for ct in self.cost])
        self.data_Ang, self.data_Angd = P[:, 0, :, :], P[:, 1, :, :]

    def set_all_layers(self, lab):
        self.data_layers = [0]
        for bnd in lab.boundaries():
            r, rd, rdd = bnd.shape.R(self.knots)
            rdr = rd / r
            r2rd2 = r ** 2 + rd ** 2
            Rad = [0, {}, {}]
            Radd = [0, {}, {}]
            kis = [0, bnd.k1, bnd.k2]
            for i in [1, 2]:
                krs = kis[i] * r
                JY = array([special.sph_jnyn(self.n, kr) for kr in krs])[:, :, :]
                Rad[i] = {'j': JY[:, 0, :], 'h': JY[:, 0, :] + 1j * JY[:, 2, :]}
                Radd[i] = {'j': JY[:, 1, :], 'h': JY[:, 1, :] + 1j * JY[:, 3, :]}

            self.data_layers.append({'ki': kis,\
                                     'r': r,\
                                     'rd': rd,\
                                     'rdd': rdd,\
                                     'rdr': rdr,\
                                     'r2rd2': r2rd2,\
                                     'Rad': Rad,\
                                     'Radd': Radd})

…


############### EBCM #############################

def mat_ebcm_axi_tm(C, m, jh1, jh2, e12, e21):
    k1 = C.ki[1]
    k2 = C.ki[2]
    Rad1 = C.Rad(m, jh1, 1)
    Radd1 = C.Radd(m, jh1, 1)
    Rad2 = C.Rad(m, jh2, 2)
    Radd2 = C.Radd(m, jh2, 2)
    Angm = C.Ang(m)
    Angmd = C.Angd(m)
    return f_utils.axitm(Rad1, Radd1, Rad2, Radd2, Angm, Angmd,\
                         C.r, C.rd, C.sint, C.cost, k1, k2, e12, C.weights)

…
```

My codes after modification, because of `special.sph_jnyn` deprecated and removed :

```
    …
    def set_funcs_ang(self):
            P = array([special.lpmn(self.n, self.n, ct) for ct in self.cost])
            self.data_Ang, self.data_Angd = P[:, 0, :, :], P[:, 1, :, :]

            print ("==============================")
            print(P.shape)
            print(self.data_Ang.shape)
            print(self.data_Angd.shape)
            print ("==============================")

        def set_all_layers(self, lab):
            self.data_layers = [0]
            for bnd in lab.boundaries():
                r, rd, rdd = bnd.shape.R(self.knots)
                rdr = rd / r
                r2rd2 = r ** 2 + rd ** 2


                Rad = [0, {}, {}]
                Radd = [0, {}, {}]
                kis = [0, bnd.k1, bnd.k2]


                for i in [1, 2]:
                    krs = kis[i] * r

                    #JY = array([special.sph_jnyn(self.n, kr) for kr in krs])[:, :, :]

                    #JY=array([[((special.spherical_jn(self.n, kr)),(special.spherical_jn(self.n, kr,1) ),(special.spherical_yn(self.n, kr) ),(special.spherical_yn(self.n, kr,1)) ) for kr in krs]])[:,:,:]
                    JY=array([[((special.spherical_jn(self.n, kr)),(special.spherical_jn(self.n, kr,1) ),(special.spherical_yn(self.n, kr) ),(special.spherical_yn(self.n, kr,1)) ) for kr in krs]])[:,:,:]

                    print("+++++++++++++++++++++++")
                    print (JY.shape)
                    print (JY)
                    print (self.n)
                    print("+++++++++++++++++++++++")

                    #Rad[i] = {'j': JY[:, 0, :], 'h': JY[:, 0, :] + 1j * JY[:, 2, :]}
                    #Radd[i] = {'j': JY[:, 1, :], 'h': JY[:, 1, :] + 1j * JY[:, 3, :]}

                    Rad[i] = {'j': JY[:, :, 0], 'h': JY[:, :, 0] + 1j * JY[:, :,2]}
                    Radd[i] = {'j': JY[:, :, 1], 'h': JY[:, :, 1] + 1j * JY[:, :, 3]}



                    #print (Rad.shape)
                    print (Rad[i])
                    print (Radd[i])
    …
    ############### EBCM #############################

def mat_ebcm_axi_tm(C, m, jh1, jh2, e12, e21):
    k1 = C.ki[1]
    k2 = C.ki[2]
    Rad1 = C.Rad(m, jh1, 1)
    Radd1 = C.Radd(m, jh1, 1)
    Rad2 = C.Rad(m, jh2, 2)
    Radd2 = C.Radd(m, jh2, 2)
    Angm = C.Ang(m)
    Angmd = C.Angd(m)


    print(Rad1.shape)
    print(Radd1.shape)
    print(Rad2.shape)
    print(Radd2.shape)
    print(Angm.shape)
    print(Angmd.shape)

    print(C.r.shape)
    print(C.rd.shape)
    print(C.sint.shape)
    print(C.cost.shape)
    #k1.shape
    #k2.shape
    #e12.shape
    print(C.weights.shape)


    #print(transpose(reshape(Angm ,Angm.size)).shape)
    #print((reversed(reshape(Angm ,Angm.size))).shape)
    print("---reshape----")


    return f_utils.axitm(Rad1, Radd1, Rad2, Radd2, Angm ,Angmd,\
                         C.r, C.rd,C.sint,C.cost, k1, k2, e12,C.weights )

    …
```

And some modification in another related file codes:

```
…

import spherical

delta_c = 1e-16
ngauss_coef =6
nrange_default = arange(2, 61)
Ms = []

    …

def methods_factory(meth_bnd_system):
    #def meth(lab, nrange=None, accuracy=1e-10, accuracy_criteria=None, ngauss=200, conv_stop=True, conv_test=False,

    def meth(lab, nrange=None, accuracy=1e-10, accuracy_criteria=None, ngauss=1, conv_stop=True, conv_test=False,
             iterative=True):

…

def meth_n(meth_bnd_system, lab, n, ngauss, ms=None, iterative=True):
    global th
    if ngauss == "auto":
        ng = ngauss_coef * n
    else:
        ng = ngauss
    C = spherical.spherical_utilities(ng, n, lab)
…
def ebcm_bnd_system(C, m, bnd, axisymm=False):
    lay = bnd.layer_no
    C.set_layer_no(lay)
    # Axisymmetric part
    if axisymm:
        Ajjtm = spherical.mat_ebcm_axi_tm(C, m, 'j', 'j', bnd.e12, bnd.e21)
…
svm = methods_factory(svm_bnd_system)
ebcm = methods_factory(ebcm_bnd_system)
pmm0 = methods_factory(pmm_bnd_system)
...
```

With the importrant part as :

> def meth(lab, nrange=None, accuracy=1e-10, accuracy_criteria=None,
>   ngauss=1, conv_stop=True, conv_test=False,
>                    iterative=True):

And

> C = spherical.spherical_utilities(ng, n, lab)

part of codes make the error:

```
############### EBCM #############################

def mat_ebcm_axi_tm(C, m, jh1, jh2, e12, e21):
    k1 = C.ki[1]
    k2 = C.ki[2]
    Rad1 = C.Rad(m, jh1, 1)
    Radd1 = C.Radd(m, jh1, 1)
    Rad2 = C.Rad(m, jh2, 2)
    Radd2 = C.Radd(m, jh2, 2)
    Angm = C.Ang(m)
    Angmd = C.Angd(m)
    return f_utils.axitm(Rad1, Radd1, Rad2, Radd2, Angm, Angmd,\
                         C.r, C.rd, C.sint, C.cost, k1, k2, e12, C.weights)
```

The output result after modification:

```
==============================
(1, 2, 3, 3)
(1, 3, 3)
(1, 3, 3)
==============================
+++++++++++++++++++++++
(1, 1, 4)
[[[ 0.04816103  0.10417659 -5.16810074 16.02904971]]]
2
+++++++++++++++++++++++
{'j': array([[0.04816103]]), 'h': array([[0.04816103-5.16810074j]])}
{'j': array([[0.10417659]]), 'h': array([[0.10417659+16.02904971j]])}
+++++++++++++++++++++++
(1, 1, 4)
[[[ 0.08151801+0.00775045j  0.12687981+0.00386415j
   -2.42490018+0.31887469j  5.12230738-1.05692606j]]]
2
+++++++++++++++++++++++
{'j': array([[0.08151801+0.00775045j]]), 'h': array([[-0.23735668-2.41714974j]])}
{'j': array([[0.12687981+0.00386415j]]), 'h': array([[1.18380587+5.12617153j]])}
(1, 0)
(1, 0)
(1, 0)
(1, 0)
(1, 2)
(1, 2)
(1,)
(1,)
(1,)
(1,)
(1,)
---reshape----
```

So ,any help will be appreciated.